# How can I list available values in workflow foundation

Tags: workflow-foundation, tfsbuild

I'm trying to write a custom code activity for my tfs build.  How can I list, or where can I get a list of available values for my activity?

Comment: What do you mean by "available values"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using an enumeration for an activity argument or variable, the values should show up in the property window for the activity. Another approach is to develop an activity designer on top of your custom activity that can provide a listing of the available choices.

Some resources on creating your own activity designers:

- http://geekswithblogs.net/jkurtz/archive/2010/01/26/137639.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd489419.aspx